# In the re-open votes queue, I cannot close as a community specific reason because "You must select a reason before submitting."

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-reopen

I'm reviewing the close votes. If I re-close as any other reason it works fine, but if I close as a "community specific reason" I can't, no matter what option I select.

[image]

I'm on Firefox 108, Manjaro Linux. I had the same problem yesterday, and it was a different computer on Windows Firefox.